# ROLLING date range in a Google Ads API Query

Tags: google-ads-api, google-query-language

```
let startDate = '2020-01-01';
let endDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10).toString();

//
"WHERE segments.date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND 'endDate' "
```

Returns this error:

> Exception: Call to GoogleAdsService.Search failed: Condition
> 'segments.date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' and 'endDate'' is invalid: BETWEEN
> operator must have exactly two values that are both numbers or both
> date strings in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

How can I set endDate to YESTERDAY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Ads Query Language accepts dates both with and without quotes. If you use the ISO-like date format with hyphens, quotes are mandatory, though.

Assuming that this is JavaScript, you can just do

```js
"WHERE segments.date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '" + endDate + "'"
```

Or using template literals (available from ES6 on, note the enclosing backticks):

```js
`WHERE segments.date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '${endDate}'`
```

Comment: Getting this error `Exception: Call to GoogleAdsService.Search failed: Error in query: unexpected input -.` Works fine when I set it in as YYYY-MM-DD, but can't figure out why ISO format doesn't work as I need it changing every day.

Comment: Can you print the actual query before sending it, just to double-check that the required quotes are actually there?

Comment: Here it is: `"WHERE segments.date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND " + endDate + " AND metrics.clicks > 0 " +`

Comment: You're missing the single quotes from my first example. Also, not sure what the extra plus is doing at the end.

Comment: Got it, I see what the problem is now. Thank you so much, works now. The plus at the end is for the ORDER clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `WHERE segments.date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND endDate`

 instead of `WHERE segments.date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND 'endDate'`

Comment: on preview returns: `Exception: Call to GoogleAdsService.Search failed: Error in WHERE clause: invalid value endDate.`

Comment: Can you try replacing endDate with YESTERDAY? @viovco

Comment: same error `Exception: Call to GoogleAdsService.Search failed: Error in WHERE clause: invalid value YESTERDAY.`